# change language automatically from code

Tags: asp.net

I use below code for change language(for example changelanguge("en") ) in C# win application how can i use sth like this in asp ?

```
public void changelanguge(String languge)
        {
            foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
            {
                if (lang.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == languge)
                {
                    Application.CurrentCulture = lang.Culture;
                    Application.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

In an ASP.NET page (ASPX) you need to override the `InitializeCulture` method:

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        this.UICulture = "";
        this.Culture = "";
    }
```

#### Option 2

In a page's markup:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="" Culture=""
```

#### Option 3

In web.config

```
<globalization culture="" uiCulture="" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

#### Option 4

Using an `HttpModule` (This sample uses ASP.NET profiles to get the language, you can change to get the language from a different source)

```
public class LocalizationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += context_PreRequestHandlerExecute;
    }

    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = sender as HttpApplication;
        var context = application.Context;
        var handler = context.Handler;
        var profile = context.Profile as CustomProfile;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            var page = handler as Page;

            if (page != null)
            {
                if (profile != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.Language))
                    {
                        page.UICulture = profile.Language;
                        page.Culture = profile.Language;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to configure it on the web.config file:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="Localization" type="Msts.Topics.Chapter06___Globalization_and_Accessibility.Lesson01___Globalization_and_Localization.LocalizationModule" />
</httpModules>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Localization" type="Msts.Topics.Chapter06___Globalization_and_Accessibility.Lesson01___Globalization_and_Localization.LocalizationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: occur error and says : colud not load `type=Msts.Topics.Chapter06___Gl...` what should i use instead of it ? and how should i change language after these steps?what should i use for `culture` and `UICulture` ?

Comment: Your type implementing `IHttpModule`

Comment: means i write `IHttpModule` for type?

Comment: Just if you follow the option 4 approach